# Combine pipe and which.min

Tags: r, dplyr

For a data frame which the columns `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` I'd like to extract that value of `B` where `A` is closest to e.g. 1 and `C` is `string1` and `D` is `string2`.

I was trying to using the pipe operator `%>%` to achieve that by

```
opt.B <- df %>%
   filter(C == 'string1') %>%
   filter(D == 'string2') %>%
   which.min(abs(A - 1))
```

which doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide example data, and expected output.

Comment: The pipe means that the 'previous result' will be used as the first parameter to the rhs-function. In your case, this means your last call is

`which.min(df %>% [...], abs(A-1) )` but that is not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
df %>%
  mutate(A1 = (abs(A - 1))) %>%
  filter(C=='A' & D == 'B') %>%
  filter(A1 == min(A1)) %>%
  select(B)

#          B
# 1 0.7191123
```

using this dataset:

```
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(

  A = runif(10),
  B = runif(10),
  C = sample(LETTERS[1:2],10,replace = T),
  D = sample(LETTERS[1:2],10,replace = T)
)

# > df
#    A         B         C D
# 1  0.9148060 0.4577418 B B
# 2  0.9370754 0.7191123 A B
# 3  0.2861395 0.9346722 B A
# 4  0.8304476 0.2554288 B B
# 5  0.6417455 0.4622928 A A
# 6  0.5190959 0.9400145 B B
# 7  0.7365883 0.9782264 A A
# 8  0.1346666 0.1174874 B A
# 9  0.6569923 0.4749971 A B
# 10 0.7050648 0.5603327 B B
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `with` to the last line of your code, to tell `which.min` that it has to look for A there.

```
my.df %>%
  filter(C == 'a') %>%
  filter(D == 'A') %>%
  with(which.min(abs(A - 1)))
# [1] 1
```

To extract the value of `B` you can use `top_n` to get the whole row and then `select(B)`/`pull(B)` like this:

```
my.df %>%
  filter(C == 'a') %>%
  filter(D == 'A') %>%
  top_n(1, -abs(A - 1)) %>% 
  select(B)

# A tibble: 1 x 1
#         B
#     <int>
#   1    11
```

If you use `top_n` with a negative sign it selects the minimum, otherwise the maximum.

**Data**

```
my.df <- tibble(A = 1:6, B = 11:16, C = rep(letters[1:3], 2), D = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 2))

my.df
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#       A     B C     D    
#   <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1    11 a     A    
# 2     2    12 b     B    
# 3     3    13 c     C    
# 4     4    14 a     A    
# 5     5    15 b     B    
# 6     6    16 c     C
```

Comment: And how do I now get the value of B at that value of A?